# Are there some known identities of elliptic polylogarithms similar to the Abel identity of polylogarithm?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, special-functions, string-theory

Let 
\begin{align}
Li_2(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}. 
\end{align}
This polylogarithm satisfies the following Abel identity:
\begin{align}
& Li_2(-x) + \log x \log y \\
& +  Li_2(-y) + \log ( \frac{1+y}{x} ) \log y \\
& +  Li_2(-\frac{1+y}{x}) + \log ( \frac{1+y}{x} ) \log (\frac{1+x+y}{xy}) \\
& +  Li_2(-\frac{1+x+y}{xy}) + \log ( \frac{1+x}{y} ) \log (\frac{1+x+y}{xy}) \\
& +  Li_2(-\frac{1+x}{y}) + \log ( \frac{1+x}{y} ) \log x \\
& = - \frac{\pi^2}{2}.
\end{align}
The following function 
\begin{align}
ELi_{n,m}(x,y,q) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j^n} \frac{y^k}{k^m} q^{jk}
\end{align}
is defined in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09457.pdf) in (2.1).

Are there some known identities similar to the Abel identity for $ELi_{n,m}(x,y,q)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there some conditions for x, and y ? for instance this paper disscussed many polylogharithms  may it help :https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9408113.pdf , because i think your class of polylogarithms is of : Dilogarithm identities and conformal weights

Answer (score 4):

The 5-term relation is a special case  of the Rogers identity: theorem 8.14 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.5236&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This is a degenerate version of the Bloch relation for elliptic dilogarithm (see page 30 [here](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/mpim/00-9/fulltext.pdf)).